# What is more efficient: one big table or separate non-related smaller ones

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am kind of new to SQL and web-programming right now, so I am doing a little project for myself to get to know every aspect of developing a website (yup, from frontend to backend and sql).

So the point is that potentially I may have a lot of data in my table, like over 3k rows [elements] (relatively a lot) with a bunch of columns [properties] as well. And I know from the beginning that it could be split on, say, four tables. For example, by color.
Each element of each color has the same amount of keys and keys itself

So the question is how I could estimate the ratio of time:memory efficiency in this case. I do understand that it is much quicker to search for information in a smaller table, but I have no idea how do SQL tables are stored. For instance, how much additional memory each table costs without.

Comment: Tables have rows and columns, not "elements" and "keys".  Your terminology prevents me (at least) from understanding what you are asking.

Comment: Ok. Over 3k rows with a bunch of columns. So elements are rows and columns are properties (edited that part)

Comment: 3k rows is very little. What do you mean that the table will be split based on color?

Comment: It depends on selected database, indexes, column types, quesries, etc. Large table (3k is small table) can be faster and slower. The easiest way is to measure it.

Comment: As I understant it MySQL tables are not stored in memory, so I do not understand your question. Maybe this question would be more suitable on [dba.se]?

Comment: My recommendation is that you research different database schema.  There are reasons for normalizing tables and reasons to not normalize them.  In most uses, normalization is the way to go.  But there are exceptions.

Comment: In general, it's better (specially when you're learning) to try and roll out some working solution, and then try to optimize it, only if it ever probes to be too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3,000 rows is *small* for SQL.  You don't want to split large tables, because SQL has strong capabilities for handling larger data.  Three come to mind:

- Sophisticated query optimizers.
- Indexes.
- Table partitions.

In addition, the way that data is stored incurs overhead for *small* tables -- not large ones.  Rows are stored on data pages.  And data pages are typically measured in thousands of bytes.  So, a small row with 100 bytes still occupies one data page -- even if the page could store one hundred such records.  And the overhead for reading the data page is the same.

In summary.  Your table isn't big.  And SQL is optimized for larger tables.  So, no need to change your data model.